# XSLT move element to another node and remove some of child elements before move

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement where I need to  move the child nodes from one element to another element and remove some of the elements after/before copy. Tried multiple options with XSLT and did not get though.

My source XML is below

```
    <root>
        <header>
            <a1>Value1</a>
            <a2>Value2</a2>
        </header>
        <body>
            <b>
                <c>
                    <d1>value3</d1>
                    <d2>value4</d2>
                </c>
                <!-- to be removed -->
                <remove1>value4</remove1>
                <remove2>value5</remove2>
            </b>
        </body>
    </root>
```

Expected output is:

```
    <root>
        <header>
            <a1>Value1</a1>
            <a2>Value2</a2>
            <body>
                <b>
                    <d1>value3</d1>
                    <d2>value4</d2>
                </b>
            </body>
        </header>
    </root>
```

My xslt is blow

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/root">
       <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/header/body/b/remove1" />
    <xsl:template match="/root/header/body/b/remove2" />
    <xsl:template match="header">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="//body" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/body" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 5):

Start your stylesheet code with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then add the template

```
<xsl:template match="c">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

to ensure the `c` is not copied but its children are and add the template

```
<xsl:template match="remove1 | remove2"/>
```

to remove the elements (to suppress they are copied).

I will add a full sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="remove1 | remove2"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms

```
<root>
    <header>
        <a1>Value1</a1>
        <a2>Value2</a2>
    </header>
    <body>
        <b>
            <c>
                <d1>value3</d1>
                <d2>value4</d2>
            </c>
            <!-- to be removed -->
            <remove1>value4</remove1>
            <remove2>value5</remove2>
        </b>
    </body>
</root>
```

into

```
<root>
    <header>
        <a1>Value1</a1>
        <a2>Value2</a2>
    </header>
    <body>
        <b>

                <d1>value3</d1>
                <d2>value4</d2>

            <!-- to be removed -->


        </b>
    </body>
</root>
```